# Dynamically compile multiple files into assembly using Rosyln

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation, runtime, roslyn

I've recently seen using CSharpCodeProvider is deprecated in .NET Core 5. I was wondering if there was a smart way to combine **multiple files** into one dll from which I can load up using Rosyln instead. I'd hate to have to stick with .NET Framework 4.7 as this is a big part of a program I'm working on.

My code used to be pretty much just this

```cs
string Files[] = Directory.GetFiles("xxxxx/bin/Debug/net5.0/Scripts", ".cs");
Parameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[1] {"xxxxx/bin/Debug/net5.0/Program.dll"}, "xxxxx/bin/Debug/net5.0/Scripts/Output/Scripts.dll");
return new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromFile(Parameters, Files).CompiledAssembly;
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in Rosyln?

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18768#issuecomment-265381303 *(PlatformNotSupportedException)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick Polyak has written a complete article on Code Project: [Using Roslyn for Compiling Code into Separate Net Modules and Assembling them into a Dynamic Library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1215168/Using-Roslyn-for-Compiling-Code-into-Separate-Net) and with complete source code [available on GitHub](https://github.com/npolyak/RoslynAssembly/).

While this might not be exactly what you are looking for, it should help you getting started with Roslyn concepts, how to create a [`CSharpCompilation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation) from a [`SyntaxTree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxtree) and emit it to a [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream).